# How to click on Search button using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click a search button with the help of selenium webdriver and python

Here is the HTML Code

```
<button data-testid="search-button" tabindex="4" type="submit" class="sc-2ry4jn-0       
sc-2ry4jn-2 sc-17kxwsy-0 bWjDpN" xpath="1"><div data-testid="icon-testid" class="sc- 
121424n-0 loEDwb"><div class="sc-121424n-2 jFTWvP"><span class="sc-1kvy6kt-0 jTNjLr sc- 
121424n-3 gCitZe" data-testid="icon:icon-jameda-SVG-icon-Search" color="#fff"><svg><use data-testid="svgcontainer-use" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
xlink:href="#icon-jameda-SVG-icon-Search"></use></svg></span></div><div color="#fff" class="sc-121424n-1 hGbob">Suchen</div></div></button>
```

```
<div data-testid="icon-testid" class="sc-121424n-0 loEDwb" xpath="1"><div class="sc- 
121424n-2 jFTWvP"><span class="sc-1kvy6kt-0 jTNjLr sc-121424n-3 gCitZe" data- 
testid="icon:icon-jameda-SVG-icon-Search" color="#fff"><svg><use data- 
testid="svgcontainer-use" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon- 
jameda-SVG-icon-Search"></use></svg></span></div><div color="#fff" class="sc-121424n-1  
hGbob">Suchen</div></div>
```

```
<div class="sc-121424n-2 jFTWvP" xpath="1"><span class="sc-1kvy6kt-0 jTNjLr sc-121424n-3  
gCitZe" data-testid="icon:icon-jameda-SVG-icon-Search" color="#fff"><svg><use data- 
testid="svgcontainer-use" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon- 
jameda-SVG-icon-Search"></use></svg></span></div>
```

```
<span class="sc-1kvy6kt-0 jTNjLr sc-121424n-3 gCitZe" data-testid="icon:icon-jameda-SVG- 
icon-Search" color="#fff" xpath="1"><svg><use data-testid="svgcontainer-use"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-jameda-SVG-icon-Search"> 
</use></svg></span>
```

To see the whole HTML Code visit:
[www.jameda.de](http://www.jameda.de) and check out the green search button in the right corner

I already tried to click it via `CLASS_NAME`, `XPATH`, `LINK_TEXT` but I always get the following error.

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Here is my code I used so far:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="sc-2ry4jn-0 sc-2ry4jn-2 sc-17kxwsy-0 bWjDpN").click()
```

The button is visible when trying to click it.

Comment: A simple xpath could be  //span[text()=' Suchen']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element  <kbd>Suchen</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.jameda.de/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class^='SearchString']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.jameda.de/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Suchen')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: jameda]

Comment: thx the CSS Selector worked. But i had to use it twice directly after another. Because first it just selects the search button, the second one is clicking it.